# Where can I find static Xerces 3.0.0 lib for AIX

Tags: c++, c, build, aix, xerces-c

I got the binaries from the xerces apache site but they only have dynamic lib.

I am wondering why they do not include static version of the lib?
And is there a place to get static Xerces 3.0.0 for AIX.

And its C version of it

Thanks for any input

P.S. Other then building it myself I am aware of this option but I want something that is more standardized. Meaning using their generic build flags that they used to build dynamic version of the lib

Comment: Typically you will be building things on your own, especially in AIX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as you mention in your postscript, download from Apache's [site](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/download.cgi) and then run the configure script:

```
./configure --enable-static
```

Comment: I am going to mark this as an answer because I ended up doing that but I was more interested where can I find out of box static xerces 3.0.0 for AIX.... it seems weird they do not distribute it with binaries considering that is what they are doing for other platforms

Comment: @grobartn I see binaries for Windows, Linux, Solaris, HPUX, and AIX. Is AIX the only one without a static library?

Comment: linux, solaris are definitely static and shared.. i am about to check HPUX...and I am talking about 32 bit libs ....but it does not make sense to me that they do not distribute static with it...but ok